# How to get over Homebrew Git conflicts?

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

I installed [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).  "brew --prefix" is /usr/local.  I've now mistakenly done things to the master branch of my local Brew Git repo that endlessly conflict with "brew update". I'd like to throw away or ignore my local changes.  Normally I'd just rm -rf repo and re-clone, but I don't think rm -rf /usr/local is wise.

How do make my local Brew Git repo happy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git reset --hard origin/master` should make everything sync up with the main Homebrew Git repo. It'll throw away any local changes you made to files tracked in the repo.